# make variable from global scope available to class after import

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I am trying to avoid refactoring a class. At the moment it picks up 'args' which comes from argparse from the global scope, but when I import this class into unittest, of course args is not there. Is it possible to make this variable available to the class after import? It is not hard to recreate the variable in the unittest file underneath the `if __name__ == "__main__":` line. But the imported class lacks that variable. Is it possible to somehow get it in there with `__dict__`  or some other trick?

An easy solution would be to have this variable go explicitly into the `__init__` upon instantiation, rather than it picking it up from the global scope. Before refactoring, I wanted to check first if there is a way to get it in there after import, when it normally goes in from the global scope. Cheers.

Comment: Maybe. Exactly how does the code import / assign `args` in the global scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggested, updating `__dict__` can be a solution. If your code is similar to this:

`file1.py`:

```
class Class:
    def foo(self):
        print(args)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = 'args'
    c = Class()
    c.foo()  # OK
```

`file.2py`:

```
import file1

c = file1.Class()
c.foo()  # will raise NameError
```

Then do `file1.__dict__['args'] = 'args'` after importing `file1`:

```
import file1

file1.__dict__['args'] = 'args'

c = file1.Class()
c.foo()  # will print args without errors
```